# Why not use 'for' instead of 'of'?

Tags: questions

He says harvesting eggs and growing the crocodile industry locally “is a very important and valuable use **of** traditional country done by traditional owners.”

[enter link description here](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/amp/crocodile-industry-hopes-to-boost-australia-aboriginal-communities/3966580.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have just read [the article](https://www.voanews.com/a/australia-crocodile-aboriginal-communities/3964779.html/) your sentence is from to put it in context. Australian First Peoples refer to their traditional lands as **country** and the use of *of* here is correct. It's a sign of respect. See [Welcome to country](http://www.usc.edu.au/learn/student-support/australian-aboriginal-and-torres-strait-islander-student-assistance/welcome-to-country-and-acknowledgement-of-traditional-custodians/).

The *Macquarie Dictionary Online* (an Australian dictionary) gives this definition of *country*:

> *Aboriginal English* traditional land with its embedded cultural values relating to the Dreamtime: the importance of country

Having said that, I would have written that sentence differently as I don't think it's well expressed.